# How to load a xsd file that is stored in my /WEB-INF folder

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, file-io, xsd

I want to load a xsd file that is stored in:

```
/WEB-INF/myxsd.xsd
```

I will be referencing this in my controller's action, not sure how to do that.

Also, since I will be referencing this all the time, is it possible for me to load it once as oppose to per request?

```
public String create() {

   // load xsd file here 

}
```

Do you use a relative path or full path?

**Update**

I have this code already that needs the xsd file where I will validate against the schema.

```
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
```

schemaFile is what I need help initializing, it seems newSchema has a few overloads (file, URI, etc.), **but this is a local file so it makes sense to get the file correct**?
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

I need help loading this xsd file from my /Web-inf/ folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The ServletContext has a method getRealPath(). So servletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF") will give you the absolute path of the WEB-INF directory.</strike>

Use ServletContext#getResourceAsStream().

To load it only once per request, you can create a field and load it lazily.

But even better would be to load it as context attribute with a lifecycle listener.

Comment: how could I do that in spring (lister)?

Comment: Don't rely on `getRealPath()`. It returns `null` when WAR is not expanded on disk but instead in memory.

Comment: @BalusC then what can I rely on?  interesting!

Comment: Use `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the Spring way of doing this would be to inject a `SchemaFactory` and `Resource` into the controller and to initialise the Schema only once. N.B. As per [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Schema.html) `Schema` is thread-safe.

```
public class MyController ... implements InitializingBean {
    private SchemaFactory schemaFactory;
    private Schema schema;
    private Resource schemaResource;

    public void setSchemaFactory(SchemaFactory schemaFactory) {
        this.schemaFactory = schemaFactory;
    }

    public void setSchemaResource(Resource schemaResource) {
        this.schemaResource = schemaResource;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Source xsdSource = new StreamSource(schemaResource.getInputStream());
        schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsdSource);
    }

    public void create() {
        // use schema
    }
}
```

And the spring config:

```
<bean id="schemaFactory" 
      class="javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory"
      factory-method="newInstance">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:constant static-field="javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="myController" class="...MyController">
    <property name="schemaFactory" ref="schemaFactory" />
    <property name="resource" value="/WEB-INF/myxsd.xsd" />
</bean>
```